# Por qué mi programa de ciclos se ejecuta diferente, si está igual de escrito. Python

Tags: python

#Este es el codigo, el primer ciclo se ejecuta bien (arroja solo 1 linea de respuesta), a partir del segundo hace multiples prints pero da el resultado (varias lineas de respuesta) y el tercero no responde. Es para un ejercicio de estudio, les agradecería si me pueden ayudar, apenas voy iniciando.Olvidé comentar solo debe arrojar el estado del paciente A, B, C y los dias que faltarían para llegar a un peso meta el cual está condicionado con el while.

```
edad = int(input("Indique la edad del paciente: "))
peso = float(input("Indique el peso del paciente: "))
etx = "#¡VALOR!"
ac = 60.1
ap = 24.4
av = 30.5
dia = 0
pesoengr = (peso*1000)

if (edad >= 5 and edad <=10):
  if peso < 16:
    estado = "A"
    dieta = ((ac*2)+(ap)+(av*2))
    while pesoengr < 22000:
      pesoengr = pesoengr + dieta
      dia = dia + 1
    print(f"El estado nutricional del paciente es {estado} y se requieren {dia} días de dieta para que alcance un peso saludable")
  elif peso > 28:
    estado = "B"
    dieta = ((ac*0.6)+(ap)+(av*4))
    while pesoengr > 24000:
      presoengr = pesoengr + dieta
      dia = dia + 1
    print(f"El estado nutricional del paciente es {estado} y se requiere {dia} días de dieta para que alcance un peso saludable")
  elif peso >=17 and peso <=27:
    estado = "C"
    dieta = ((ac*0.5)+(ap*0.7)+(av*2))
    while pesoengr < 28000:
      pesoengr = pesoengr + dieta
      dia = dia + 1
      print(f"El estado nutricional del paciente es {estado} y se requiere {dia} días de dieta para que alcance un peso máximo")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inicialmente veo dos problemas:

```
  elif peso > 28:
    estado = "B"
    dieta = ((ac*0.6)+(ap)+(av*4))
    while pesoengr > 24000:
      presoengr = pesoengr + dieta # <-- Adicional hay un typo en pResoengr
      dia = dia + 1
```

En esta opción, para empezar, hay un *typo* en `presoengr = ...` hay una `r` de más.
Y lo siguiente es que cuando el peso es mayor a 28, la variable `pesoengr` siempre será **mayor que 28,000** y dentro del `while` `pesoengr` se seguirá incrementando porque le estás sumando `dieta`, entonces `pesoengr` SIEMPRE será `> 24,000`. Esto creará un **ciclo infinito**.
**Solución:** Corrige la formula `presoengr = pesoengr + dieta`, incluyendo el *typo*. 
Posiblemente sea `pesoengr = pesoengr - dieta`, con signo menos [`-`].

---

En esta otra parte del código:

```
  elif peso >=17 and peso <=27:
    estado = "C"
    dieta = ((ac*0.5)+(ap*0.7)+(av*2))
    while pesoengr < 28000:
      pesoengr = pesoengr + dieta
      dia = dia + 1
      print(f"El estado nutricional del paciente es {estado} y se requiere {dia} días de dieta para que alcance un peso máximo")
#     ^___ Saca este print del while.
```

Obviamente va a imprimir múltiples veces porque hay un `print` dentro del `while`, así que por cada iteración va a mandar algo a la pantalla.
**Solución:** mueve el `print` 2 espacios a la izquierda, justo al nivel de los otros `print()`.